# Crontab expression to schedule a DAG for First weekday every month

Tags: cron, airflow

- I tried `0 10 1W * *` to run the dag at 10:00 on first weekday of every month
- but Airflow says it as an invalid CRON expression.

where am i going wrong?

Comment: By first weekday, do you mean first day of the month, or first Sunday/Monday of month?

Comment: I recommend using https://crontab.guru/ to play around with the schedule.